# Texturing 3d Object with UV Map OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-mapping, 3d-rendering

I have a problem with rendering of a 3D Object with UV Map.

First of all my object is in Wavefront model.I use a parser that splits the whole file to vertices,normals,faces and texCoords. After parsing the file.obj i have all of them.

The problem is that texture does not appear to the final result but the object without texturing.

This is the init function:

```
int init()
{
if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0)
{
    cout << "SDL error: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
    return false;
}

// SDL Window crap
createWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, 32, false, "WaveFront Object Loader");
reshape(screenWidth, screenHeight);

// OpenGL init
// Stuff
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.0f);
glClearDepth(1.0f);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_FASTEST);

// Face culling (for textures)
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_BACK); 
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

// Lighting
GLfloat light_ambient[] = { 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0 };
GLfloat light_diffuse[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
GLfloat light_specular[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
GLfloat light_position[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 };

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, light_ambient);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_diffuse);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, light_specular);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);

glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

// Object loader
if(!model.load("BallForRenderl.obj"))
{
    cout << "Could not load model" << endl;
    return false;
}


return true;
 }
```

This is the function that draws the scene:

```
void draw(){

    glPushMatrix();

// clear the screen & depth buffer
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// set the perspective projection
glCallList(g_persp);

// set the camera position
gluLookAt(  0, 1, -20,  //  eye pos
            0, 0, 0,    //  aim point
            0, 1, 0);   //  up direction

glRotatef(angle, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0);
glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);


glScalef(0.2,0.2,0.2);

model.draw();

// set the orthographic projection
glCallList(g_ortho);

// 2D/text  *****************************************

glPopMatrix();

// Commented out because we call it in our idle() function - maintains framerate independance
// SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
}
```

And this is the function that draws the model:

```
void WFObject::draw(){

glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE); 
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); 
glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0); 
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

for(int f = 0; f < faces.size(); f++)
{
    glNormal3f(normals[faces[f].vn1 - 1].x, normals[faces[f].vn1 - 1].y, normals[faces[f].vn1 - 1].z);
    glVertex3f(vertices[faces[f].v1 - 1].x, vertices[faces[f].v1 - 1].y, vertices[faces[f].v1 - 1].z);
    glTexCoord2f(texCoords[faces[f].vt1 - 1].u,texCoords[faces[f].vt1 - 1].v);
    //printf("%f %f \n",texCoords[faces[f].vt1 - 1].u,texCoords[faces[f].vt1 - 1].v);
    glNormal3f(normals[faces[f].vn2 - 1].x, normals[faces[f].vn2 - 1].y, normals[faces[f].vn2 - 1].z);
    glVertex3f(vertices[faces[f].v2 - 1].x, vertices[faces[f].v2 - 1].y, vertices[faces[f].v2 - 1].z);
    glTexCoord2f(texCoords[faces[f].vt2 - 1].u,texCoords[faces[f].vt2 - 1].v);
    //printf("%f %f \n",texCoords[faces[f].vt2 - 1].u,texCoords[faces[f].vt2 - 1].v);
    glNormal3f(normals[faces[f].vn3 - 1].x, normals[faces[f].vn3 - 1].y, normals[faces[f].vn3 - 1].z);
    glVertex3f(vertices[faces[f].v3 - 1].x, vertices[faces[f].v3 - 1].y, vertices[faces[f].v3 - 1].z);
    glTexCoord2f(texCoords[faces[f].vt3 - 1].u,texCoords[faces[f].vt3 - 1].v);
    //printf("%f %f \n",texCoords[faces[f].vt3 - 1].u,texCoords[faces[f].vt3 - 1].v);
    //printf("\n");
}

glEnd();
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

}

I know that maybe i miss something but i cannot solve this although i read a lot of tutorials.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Well if you want to use a texture, you have to __load it__ first... There's no place in your code when you bind anything to a texture buffer.

Comment: @PawełStawarz I get the UV coordinates from the wavefront files.

Comment: The UV coordinates aren't the same as a texture. A texture is a bitmap, the UV coordinates map the pixels of the bitmap to the points of hte mesh. UV coordinates alone won't texture your model. Here's some reading for you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_Mapping

Comment: Thanks for your answer @PawełStawarz. I had to read a little more with your suggestion and combine the info of imported bitmap and uv coordinates. Finally this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
glNormal3f(...);
glVertex3f(...);
glTexCoord2f(...);  // this will affect the *next* vertex
```

Wrong order.

> glVertex commands are used within glBegin/glEnd pairs to specify
>   point, line, and polygon vertices.  **The current color, normal, texture
>   coordinates, and fog coordinate are associated with the vertex when glVertex
>   is called.**

You need to call `glTexCoord()` *before* the `glVertex()` you want it to belong to:

```
glNormal3f(...);
glTexCoord2f(...);
glVertex3f(...);
```

---

You also never seem to bind a texture object (via `glBindTexture()`) anywhere.  You need to bind a texture object so OpenGL knows which texture to sample from.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed the order but it has not any difference. No texture again.

Comment: glBindTexture() with argument a bitmap image solved my problem.